# How can I Give a JTextPane a different width than the main JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextpane

So, when I create a JTextPane and add it to a JFrame, it fills up the frame, moving with it. How do I stop this so I can do pane.setSize?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to create a JPanel and add the JTextPane to the panel.  Then you can add the panel to the frame.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(null);

JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();

panel.add(pane);

this.add(panel); //assuming that this extends JFrame
```

You should now be able to resize the text pane appropriately.

Comment: This relies on the default layout of `JPanel()` being `FlowLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

`JFrame` has implemented `BorderLayout` in the API, then

`JFrame.add(JTextPane)` equals `JFrame.add(JTextPane, BorderLayout.CENTER)`

if is there only one `JComponent` placed into `JFrame`, then (center area) fills all available `Dimension` that returns container

no idea what do you rally to want to do

1. use proper `LayoutManager`
2. use `JScrollPane`

Answer (score 1):

Create a new gridBagLayout and set the GridBagConstraints accordingly.

```
Container pane;
pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c;
    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.ipady = 0;
    c.weightx = 1.0;
    c.weighty = 1.0;
    c.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    pane.add(jsp, c);
     pane.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    getContentPane().add(pane);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("TITLE");
    setLocation(150, 50);
    pack();
    setSize(600, 800);
```